# How to fix the error "exception while signaling: Must be a LuaSourceContainer" , which came up while trying to make my game in Roblox studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

SO this is related to roblox studio..so my code used to work just fine couple weeks ago, and now all of a sudden it says exception while signaling: Must be a LuaSourceContainer. Well honestly i cannot recall if i did edit the script or not, but i dont find any error in the code it self. And the error doesnt show the line which the error should be in.

Could u guys simply telll me why this occurs, and ways to overcome this problem.
Thank you

Ive tried doing google search and other yt stuff, but couldnt figure out the problem yet...